# Python 3 Write class to return surface area and volume of sphere

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, volume

I have tried everything and my code seems to be very close but i keep getting a name error when i have defined the variable.

```
from math import *

class Spheres:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = r
        self.area = 0
        self.volume = 0

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def surfaceArea(self):
        self.area = 4 * 3.14 * (r*r)
        return (self.area)

    def getVolume(self):
        self.volume = (4/3) * 3.14 * (r * r * r)
        return (self.volume)


def main():
    r = input("Enter the radius of the sphere: ")
    s = Spheres(r)
    print("The volume of the sphere is: ", s.surfaceArea())
    print("The surface area of the sphere is: ", s.volume())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 30, in <module> main() 
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 26, in main print("The volume of the sphere is: ", s.surfaceArea()) 
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 15, in surfaceArea self.area = 4 * 3.14 * (r*r) 
NameError: global name 'r' is not defined
```

Comment: What's the `NameError`? Can you please include it in your question?

Comment: Also, check your code indentation. Does the indentation above accurately reflect how your actual code is indented?

Comment: No the functions under classes are all indented like the first one and the error is:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 26, in main
    print("The volume of the sphere is: ", s.surfaceArea())
  File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 15, in surfaceArea
    self.area = 4 * 3.14 * (r*r)
NameError: global name 'r' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def surfaceArea(self):
    self.area = 4 * 3.14 * (r*r)
    return (self.area)

def getVolume(self):
    self.volume = (4/3) * 3.14 * (r * r * r)
    return (self.volume)
```

In functions above change all r's to `self.radius` cause `self.radius` is the corresponding attribute of your class not r ...

also there are some minor mistakes in your `__init__`, correct your class as follows:

```
class Spheres:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r
        self.area = 0
        self.volume = 0

    def getRadius(self):
        return self.radius

    def surfaceArea(self):
        r=self.radius
        self.area = 4 * 3.14 * (r*r)
        return (self.area)

    def getVolume(self):
        r=self.radius
        self.volume = (4/3) * 3.14 * (r * r * r)
        return (self.volume)
```

Comment: that gives me: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: instead of r = input("Enter the radius of the sphere: ") do this: r = int(input("Enter the radius of the sphere: "))

Comment: now i get:File "/local/files/jfult001/CSC221/lab10/9ball.py", line 27, in main
    print("The surface area of the sphere is: "), s.volume()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I've edited my answer and re-written your class, did you check it out?

Comment: yes but i still get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: That's odd cause it's working perfect here! also check @Joel Cornett answer, it will give you a better view of how variables work in python. Keep in mind that the output of "input" is always a string, that means you can't do mathematical works on it. in order to do it, you should change it into a number somewhere in your code. for example you can do it in your __ init __.  play with it a little.

Comment: says there is a problem with this line: print("The volume of the sphere is: ", s.surfaceArea())

Comment: @JoelCornett i use asterisks for multiplication, just for some reason it has a problem with the print line. and says type error 'int' is not callable

Comment: @user2306249: Oh sorry, just looked at your code again. I think you meant to do `s.getVolume()`, not `s.volume()` in the `print` statement.

Comment: @user2306249 good. offtopic: math has a constant named pi. if you are dealing with spherical shapes, you can use it instead of 3.14.

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you about *scopes*:

In Python, variables are *scoped*, or limited, to the code that they are defined in. Take the below code for example:

```
def my_function():
    r = 1234

print r
```

This will give you a `NameError`, because `r` is *local* to `my_function()` and doesn't exist outside of `my_function()`.

Similarly:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def access_r(self):
        return r

m = MyClass(1234)
m.access_r()
```

This code will also give you a `NameError` because `r` is only defined in the scope of `__init__()`.

Notice, however that in the above example, you have `self.radius = r`. It just so happens that `self` is accessible in *both* functions. The value of `r` is stored in `self.radius` for the express purpose of accessing it from within other functions inside the same class. Take the following modification, for example:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def access_r(self):
        return self.radius

m = MyClass(1234)
print m.access_r()
```

This code will run smoothly *and* return `1234`, the value of `r`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'r' is input as a string.

I would write r=float(input("Enter radius:"))